# Convert an Array with objects in in it into a Json

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, doctrine

Actually I'm working with Symfony 2.8, an I'm trying to use AJAX to get information of an id given.
This is how I use Ajax in my html.twig :

```
$.ajax({
        url: '{{ (path('questionsByAudit')) }}',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
         "idAudit": $(this).attr('data-id')
        },
        async: true,
        success: function (data)
        {
         console.log(data);
         alert(data);
        }
      });
```

This Is my URL in my routing.yml:

```
questionsByAudit: 
    path: /QuestionsByAudit
    defaults: { _controller: FSABundle:FsaPlan/FsaPlanByAuditor:getQuestions }
```

And this is the function in the controller:

```
public function getQuestionsAction(Request $request )
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();



        if($request->request->get('idAudit')){

            $idAudit = $request->request->get('idAudit');

            $Audit = $em->getRepository('FSABundle:FsaAudits')
                    ->findBy(array('idAudit'=>$idAudit));

            return new JsonResponse($Audit);
        }
    }
```

THe problem is that the next function returns this:
[image: $Audit Result]

And this is what I get when I print the result in an alert:
[image: Result of the Ajax printed in an alert]

This is what I get in console.log:
[image: Result in console.log]

> **NOTE:** I've read that the way to return the information of the controller to the ajax call should be as a JSON, but I think that what I get in $Audit is an array with objects inside, I don't know how to return that information to the Ajax correctly.
>   
>   **Any Idea or suggestion how can I get it?**

Comment: one hint I can give you: `alert` is probably the worst way to check any variable. you are already using `console.log`, why not show that instead?

Comment: don't `alert` objects. use `console.log` instead

Comment: ok, let me add it in my question

Comment: Return response like `$response = new Response(json_encode($result)); return $response;`

Comment: I've already edited my question

Comment: Serialize your object. https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/components/serializer.html

Answer (score 0):

In Controller Function Return Json Response.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

        $result['success'] = "1";   
        $result['data'] = $data;   
        $result['message'] = "Successfully Update"; 

        $response = new Response(json_encode($result));
        return $response;
```

Comment: what $data would be?

Comment: It returns the same :( data: [{...}] ->0: { }

Answer (score 0):

one simple approach would be to implement [`JsonSerializable`](https://www.php.net/jsonserializable) on the objects you want to encode

```
class FsaAudits implements \JsonSerializable {

   // ... all other content

   public function jsonSerialize() {
       return (array)$this; // this might only contain an empty array
   }
}
```

however, it's better to actually control what is output (don't want truely internal data to leak):

```
public function jsonSerialize() {
    return [
        'idAudit' => $this->idAudit,
        //...
    ];
}
```

another way would be to use Symfony's Serializer component.

Comment: If I post my FsaAudits entity, could you help me with that?

Comment: I know, just I'm asking you for help but thanks for the suggestion :)